# Importing list from java.awt or java.utils

Tags: java

I am new to java so maybe this is very trivial question.

But I just noticed that when i declared

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

Eclipse IDE gave me bunch of options for "List" error.

Mainly.. the top 2 one got me curious.

What is the difference if I use java.awt vs java.utils ??

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`java.awt.List` is [List component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) (like drop down list), it not a collection/datastructure.

> What is the difference if I use java.awt vs java.utils ??

You can't use List/Collection specific methods like [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29).

Comment: Also, note that Java.awt.list (awt being the abstract window toolkit) is actually a gui element that contains a list of entries, rather than a data structure meant to store a list of data. (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/List.html for more detail)

Answer (score 5):

awt.List is a List component used in GUI where as java.util.List is an interface for the lists data structure

Answer (score 1):

`java.awt.List` is an awt component. Don't use it in your case. You need `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 0):

AWT or abstract windowing toolkit is GUI toolkit in java and contains classes that are required for 2D elements.
awt.list is used to get select-box/drop-down list in your application.

Use util.list in your case.