# Print a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, printing

I would like to print a List in Java.

```
r1
r2
r3
r4
```

Here is the code:

```
public static final void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

    String r1, r2, r3, r4;

    System.out.print("Enter word..");
    r1 = a.next();

    System.out.print("Enter second word");
    r2 = a.next();

    System.out.print("Enter third word");
    r3 = a.next();

    System.out.print("Enter last word");
    r4 = a.next();

    List list = new List();
    list.add(r1);
    list.add(r2);
    list.add(r3);
    list.add(r4);

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

How do I get it print my list rather then:

```
java.awt.List[list0,0,0,0x0,invalid,selected=null]
```

Comment: You proabably want to use `java.util.ArrayList` not `java.awt.List` it will print out in a different way. `awt` classes are GUI controls

Comment: The suggestions you already got is much better, but I'd still like to mention that you use `for` loop to iterate through your list and `System.out.print` to print all elements on the same line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On top of your class you have:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

However, `java.awt.List` describes a GUI component and is probably not what you want. To use the data structure `List` change the import to:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Since [`java.util.List<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is a generic interface, you should also use it appropriately:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

The expression `System.out.println(list);` will print the `List` object which may or may not show the contents (depending on the implementation of `toString`). To display the contents of the list, it will need to be iterated:

```
for ( String str : list ) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

---

As noted in the comment, this solution will only work if you also `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: Note that `import java.util.List;` will make `List` available but not `ArrayList`.  Thus, the above will not compile.  You need to either add `import java.util.ArrayList;`, or (my preference) change it to `import java.util.*;`.

Comment: @ajb: Updated the answer to include that info.

Answer (score 3):

java.awt.List is List component (like drop down list as you would see in a GUI) 
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163687/importing-list-from-java-awt-or-java-utils).)

[image: A drop down list]

Where java.util.List is an ordered collection for you to store your data. ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html))

Try changing your import (as jlordo mentioned) from

```
import java.awt.List;
```

to

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

    String r1, r2, r3, r4;

    System.out.print("Enter word..");
    r1 = a.next();

    System.out.print("Enter second word");
    r2 = a.next();

    System.out.print("Enter third word");
    r3 = a.next();

    System.out.print("Enter last word");
    r4 = a.next();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(r1);
    list.add(r2);
    list.add(r3);
    list.add(r4);

    for ( String str : list )
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Instead of printing your user's input you printed the object instead.

Comment: Answers should have some textual explanation/description. Posting just code encourages `cargo-culting` and does not help with understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way would be perhaps to  use `StringBuilder`

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Add the stuff here.
        ...

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s: list)
            sb.append(s + " ");

        System.out.println(sb);
```